# Multi Column Paragraphs

Tags: multicolumn

How would split these two paragraphs into two columns so they're side-by-side?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section*{Chapter 28}

\paragraph*{Magnetic Field $\boldsymbol{\vec{B}}$}
A magnetic field $\vec{B}$ is defined in terms of the force $
\vec{F_B}$ acting on a test particle with charge $q$ moving through the field with velocity 
$\vec{v}$:
$$\vec{F_B}=q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$$
The SI unit for $\vec{B}$ is the \textbf{tesla}(T): 1 T = 1 N/(A$\cdot$m) = $10^4$ gauss.

\paragraph*{The Hall Effect}
When a conducting strip carrying a current $i$ is placed in a uniform magnetic field 
$\vec{B}$, some charge carriers (with charge $e$) build up on one side of the conductor, 
creating a potential difference $V$ across the strip. The polarities of the sides indicate 
the sign of the charge carriers.

\end{document}
```

Comment: please, make from your code snippet full, small document, which we can compile! Welcome to TeX.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\paragraph*{Magnetic Field $\boldsymbol{\vec{B}}$}
A magnetic field $\vec{B}$ is defined in terms of the force $
\vec{F_B}$ acting on a test particle with charge $q$ moving through the field with velocity
$\vec{v}$:
\[
\vec{F_B}=q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}
\]
The SI unit for $\vec{B}$ is the \textbf{tesla}(T): 1 T = 1 N/(A$\cdot$m) = $10^4$ gauss.
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\paragraph*{The Hall Effect}
When a conducting strip carrying a current $i$ is placed in a uniform magnetic field
$\vec{B}$, some charge carriers (with charge $e$) build up on one side of the conductor,
creating a potential difference $V$ across the strip. The polarities of the sides indicate
the sign of the charge carriers.
\end{minipage}
```

I anticipate, that this can be one of possible solution.

Comment: The usual recommendation about `$$` applies. `;-)`